# In VB.NET, how to call a property's Getter without using its value?

Tags: vb.net

Suppose I have a third-party library with a shared (static) property with a getter that initializes some state, and I want to call it without using the returned value.  Obviously, if that property on foo is named Bar, I could do:

```
Dim dummy = foo.Bar
```

Is there a good way to call this that doesn't require the dummy reference?

Comment: Why would you not what this to happen? Bypassing normal code execution in closed source libraries sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question--I do want it to happen, but I have no use for the "dummy" reference.  I want to call foo.Bar now and then call foo.Bar later as needed.

Comment: If this property getter has side-effects, I'd be fearful of this library.

Comment: In C#: `void TouchForEffect(object v) {}; .. TouchForEffect(foo.Bar)`. It still uses the value, but otherwise avoids the error and "adds intent" :)

Comment: Is the "third party library" from you or one of your fellows? Properties should never have side-effects (getter not at all). Obviously this property wants to be  a method.

Comment: @user2246674: Clever, you should post it as an answer ;-)

Comment: user1 and Tim, I agree.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I did misunderstand, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you try to call it without assigning the value:

```
foo.Bar
```

the error message is pretty clear:

> Property access must assign to the property or use its value.

Property getters should just return state and shouldn't have any side-effects, so it makes no sense to call it without using the return value. It's an unfortunate design by the third-party library.